# Parsing a text file with regex

Tags: regex, file, parsing

For example, I have a sample text file as displayed below that I need to fetch information from:

```
Sider_DLL: version 6.3.9 (0)
Filename_match: PES2020.exe
handle1 = 40923
debug = 0
game_priority_class = 0x0
livecpk_enabled = 1
lookup_cache_enabled = 1
lua_enabled = 1
lua_gc_opt = step
jit_enabled = 1
luajit_ext_enabled = 1
dummify_uniparam = 1
key-cache_ttl_sec = 10
rewrite-cache.ttl-sec = 10
cache.size = 32
```

I am wondering if I can use regex in order to get the data in lines 1,2,9, and 13 and output a concatenated string: "version 6.3.9(0)PES2020.exestep10". I have the following line and does not return the right output.

```
re.findall(r'Sider_DLL:: (\\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\s\d+)[ a-zA-Z]+Filename_match:(a-z)+[ a-zA-Z]+lua_gc_opt= (a-zA-Z))
```

Comment: Probably, yes.  Give it a go and let us know if you run into any issues :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
You need to first give it a go and we might be able to help if you can isolate a specific problem. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also find the data using 4 capture groups, and output the 4 concatenated groups like `$1$2$3$4`

```php
^Sider_DLL: *(\w.*)\r?\nFilename_match: *(\w.*)(?:\r?\n(?!lua_gc_opt *=).*)*\r?\nlua_gc_opt *= *(\w.*)(?:\r?\n(?!key-cache_ttl_sec *=).*)*\r?\nkey-cache_ttl_sec *= *(\d+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `Sider_DLL: *(\w.*)\r?\n` Match start of line 1, and capture in **group 1** a word char followed by the rest of the line and newline
- `Filename_match: *(\w.*)` Match start of line 2 and capture in **group 2** a word char followed by the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!lua_gc_opt *=).*)*\r?\n` Match all the lines that do not start with `lua_gc_opt =`
- `lua_gc_opt *= *(\w.*)` Match `lua_gc_opt =` and capture in **group 3** a word char and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!key-cache_ttl_sec *=).*)*\r?\n` Match all lines that do not start with `key-cache_ttl_sec =`
- `key-cache_ttl_sec *= *(\d+)` Match `key-cache_ttl_sec =` and capture in **group 4** one or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/va6Dcr/1)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"^Sider_DLL: *(\w.*)\r?\nFilename_match: *(\w.*)(?:\r?\n(?!lua_gc_opt *=).*)*\r?\nlua_gc_opt *= *(\w.*)(?:\r?\n(?!key-cache_ttl_sec *=).*)*\r?\nkey-cache_ttl_sec *= *(\d+)"

test_str = ("Sider_DLL: version 6.3.9 (0)\n"
            "Filename_match: PES2020.exe\n"
            "handle1 = 40923\n"
            "debug = 0\n"
            "game_priority_class = 0x0\n"
            "livecpk_enabled = 1\n"
            "lookup_cache_enabled = 1\n"
            "lua_enabled = 1\n"
            "lua_gc_opt = step\n"
            "jit_enabled = 1\n"
            "luajit_ext_enabled = 1\n"
            "dummify_uniparam = 1\n"
            "key-cache_ttl_sec = 10\n"
            "rewrite-cache.ttl-sec = 10\n"
            "cache.size = 32")

result = ["".join(m) for m in re.findall(regex, test_str)]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['version 6.3.9 (0)PES2020.exestep10']
```

Comment: Would it work in Python too using replace or you would need a loop to concatenate the string?

Comment: @tremayne you could use re.findall which returns the values of all groups in a list and then join those values if you want.

Comment: @tremayne I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: The code worked fine but when I tried with the original text file the return concatenated string was empty:  my_file = open("sample.txt", "r") 
content = my_file.read()                                                                                                                 result = ["".join(m) for m in re.findall(regex, content)]
print(result)

Comment: @tremayne I think the contents of the file is in `content` right? Perhaps like this `re.findall(regex, content)`

Comment: Excuse that mistake; I included content. I did not get error it was empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231710/discussion-between-tremayne-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^.*?Sider_DLL:\s*(.*?)\r?\n.*?Filename_match:\s*(.*?)\r?\n.*?lua_gc_opt\s*=\s*(.*?)\r?\n.*?key-cache_ttl_sec\s*=\s*(.*?)\r?\n.*$
Replace: $1$2$3$4
```

### Demo